# How to update a field in a DE using sql?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I have a DE where i have 3 fields(cost price , selling price and on sale).If the selling price>cost price...then on sale field should be updated as "True"(on sale is boolean field.).What is the query for that?

Comment: could you please check if the SQL statement works out for you. If so, please mark my answer as accepted, so others can easily see that your issue has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the comparison to your select via a CASE-statement as directly writing it into the select isn't supported in Transact SQL. Make sure to add the column name as alias to the case result.

To update a data extension it is important to add an id field (primary key) to it as well as the query, as this is used to identify the record.

The SQL query activity needs to be set to the "Update" mode.

```sql
SELECT
    YourIdField,
    CASE WHEN SellingPrice > CostPrice THEN
        1
    ELSE
        0
    END as OnSale
FROM
    YOUR_DE_NAME
```

Comment: syntax near True is incorrect ,it says

Comment: 1 for true and 0 for false will work  -- since they're the bit datatype behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks Adam, was in a hurry and didn't test the query yesterday. Updated my answer now.